# C interoperability with Swift

Tags: ios, c, arrays, swift, struct

I have included a C struct within my Swift 2.2 iOS project.  The C struct is exposed via a header files as:

```
   #define NUM_BINS 10;
   typedef struct
   {
       float bin_size;
       unsigned short counts[NUM_BINS];
       unsigned int cleanSamples;
       unsigned short compressCount;
       unsigned short totalSamples;
       bool isMature;
   } SD;
```

I then try to declare this struct in Swift via:

```
    var counts: [UInt16] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    let sd = SD(bin_size: 500, counts: counts, cleanSamples: 0, compressCount: 0, totalSamples: 0, isMature: false)
```

but receive the following error:

**Cannot convert value of type '[UInt16]' to expected argument type '(UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16)'**

How can I translate this from C to Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: Try getting rid of the brackets around UInt16

Comment: What happens if you use `counts: &counts` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed-size C arrays turn into Swift tuples rather than Swift arrays. (See [here](https://twitter.com/warrenm/status/615558392279465984) for some unfortunate consequences.) So instead of

```
var counts: [UInt16] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

you need something like

```
var counts = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I haven't found anything in Apple's official documentation saying this, by the way. I don't know whether that's reason to worry that it might change in the future...